# Command Line Control Flow Graph

Tags: java, command-line, control-flow-graph

Is there some tool that will, from the command line, produce a human-readable control flow graph? Preferably text based rather than a picture.

Nearly every CFG generator I've seen is an eclipse plugin which slows things down considerably.

EDIT: Exclusively java here.